# Mysql select with probabilities and conditions

Tags: mysql, select, conditional-statements

I have a mysql table called `words` which contains a `score`column with values that range from 0 to 3 (decimals are valid).

How can I select 50 words from which 70% have `score` > 2.14 and `score` <3, 20% with `score` > 1.08 and `score` <= 2.14, and finally, 10% with `score` <= 1.08?

Thanks in advance

---

**EDIT:** I have managed to get really to close but I am still missing something. This is my query:

```
SELECT
  palabra4.*, rndview.rndFactor, FLOOR(palabra4.factor)
FROM
  palabra4
  JOIN (
    SELECT
      CASE
    WHEN aleatorio < 0.1 THEN 1
    WHEN aleatorio < 0.8 THEN 3
    ELSE 2
      END as rndFactor
    FROM
      (SELECT @rnd:=rand() as aleatorio FROM palabra4 LIMIT 10) AS rndinit
  ) AS rndview ON rndview.rndFactor=FLOOR(palabra4.factor)
GROUP BY palabra4.id
ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 10
```

I will explain it section by section:

```
SELECT @rnd:=rand() as aleatorio FROM palabra4 LIMIT 10
```

This code above returns a list of 10 random numbers between 0 and 1.

```
    SELECT
      CASE
    WHEN aleatorio < 0.1 THEN 1
    WHEN aleatorio < 0.8 THEN 3
    ELSE 2
      END as rndFactor
    FROM
      (SELECT @rnd:=rand() as aleatorio FROM palabra4 LIMIT 10) AS rndinit
```

This returns a list of 10 numbers that can only be 1, 2 or 3 according to the specified probabilities.
However, when I join it just takes all matches. How can I get only a random entry per rndview's row?

Comment: write a query which calculates those buckets, then join against it to fetch the rest of the data

Comment: I want exactly 50 rows without repetition but what if the `words` table does not fit the minimum number of entries required for each percent?. I could fill the gap with words from the first group... how can I make sure to not repeat any entry? Wouldn't this be very expensive? no cheaper way?

Comment: @omniyo:You will need to read through the whole table no matter what you do